# Meaning of "mat" in this André Gide passage

Tags: sens, vocabulaire

The question is on *mat* in this passage from La Porte étroite by André Gide.

> Lucile Bucolin ne prenait que peu de part à notre vie ; elle ne descendait de sa chambre que passé le repas de midi ; elle s’allongeait aussitôt sur un sofa ou dans un hamac, demeurait étendue jusqu’au soir et ne se relevait que languissante. Elle portait parfois à son front, pourtant parfaitement **mat**, un mouchoir comme pour essuyer une moiteur ; c’était un mouchoir dont m’émerveillaient la finesse et l’odeur qui semblait moins un parfum de fleur que de fruit ; parfois elle tirait de sa ceinture un minuscule miroir à glissant couvercle d’argent, qui pendait à sa chaîne de montre avec divers objets ; elle se regardait, d’un doigt touchait sa lèvre, cueillait un peu de salive et s’en mouillait le coin des yeux.

**Question**

What does it mean?

**Background**

I have looked at [this](http://www.wordreference.com/fren/mat#) and [this](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mat) dictionary entry.

The primary meaning seems to be *not reflecting light* or *unpolished*.  Are we saying that her forehead, having no perspiration on it, was perfectly unreflective and that her wiping of sweat was an affectation?

Alternatively, the first linked French-English dictionary says that the word means *olive* when said of skin.  But what is *perfectly olive*?  And why is someone of perfect olive skin not expected to wipe her forehead, as seems to be implied by *pourtant*?

As if to increase my confusion, an English translation says:

> She used sometimes to raise a handkerchief to her forehead as if wiping away some imaginary moisture, though her skin was a perfection of smooth purity

I am baffled.

Comment: "her forehead, having no perspiration on it, was perfectly unreflective and that her wiping of sweat was an affectation". Definitely yes for me. Literary translations are never (must never) be literal - so looking at a translation is not the best way to learn word for word vocabulary. A literary translation has to be judged in the context of the whole work. Her skin was a "perfection of smooth purity" means it showed  no imperfections, was even in colour, drops of perspiration would have showed irregularities in colour and surface.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D'après [wikipedia](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mat), **mat** signifie : **Qui n’a pas d’éclat, qui ne réfléchit pas la lumière**

Dans ce contexte cela sous entend que **la peau ne brille pas, grâce à l'absence de sueur** et qu'il n'y a donc pas besoin de l'essuyer avec un mouchoir.

Je penses que **le traducteur a préféré une traduction littéraire à une traduction littérale**. Le sens littérale original du texte est perdu en changeant "mat" par "smooth" alors que le mot anglais "matte/mat/mate" a le même sens qu'en français ([having a dull or lusterless surface](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mat?s=t)). Je suppose qu'il a estimé que si sa peau comportait des gouttes de sueur elle ne serait pas "lisse" - et que l'essuyer avec un mouchoir la rendrait de nouveau lisse.

Selon moi c'est une faute ; la traduction littérale devrait être utilisée quand c'est possible, sous peine de remplacer le style de l'auteur par le style du traducteur.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I may grudgingly accept *smooth*, but simply cannot see anything like *perfection of purity* in the original text.

Comment: Agreed, the english text make Lucile Bucolin's skin beautiful and perfect when the french text just state she's not sweating.